# How to keep image structure the same after altering zoom on webpage

Tags: css, html

Hi I am having trouble keeping the structure the same on the webpage because when I zoom in or zoom out it alters everything. I want it so that when the webpage is zoomed in or zoomed out it does not alter the design.

What the structure looks like when it is in 100% webpage zoom

[image]

When I zoom in to 110% this is what happens. it pushes the other picture down when I want it to remain the same structure as 100%

[image]

```
<section class='images'>
<img class="review-img" src="./images/flower.jpg"></img></a>
<img class="review-img" src="./images/flower.jpg"></img></a>
<img class="review-img" src="./images/flower.jpg"></img></a>
<img class="review-img" src="./images/zoo1.jpg"></img>
</section>

.images {
margin-bottom: 0px;
background-position: center;
text-align: center;
margin-left:170px;
margin-right:170px;

}

.review-img {
width: 210px;
margin: 40px;
height: 320px;
border: solid 5px white;
}
```

Comment: both the images looks same to me except the rat went for lunch in 2nd one.

Comment: It got pushed down I didnt show it

Comment: Could you upload codepen?

Comment: What is happening here is that when you zoom in there is not enough room for the 4th image image so it falls down to a second row.

What you can do is increase the size of the containing element that the images are in so that there is enough room at this zoom level to display the images

Comment: Would I increase the size of the containing element just by increasing the width

Comment: How do I increase the size of the containing element

Comment: Let us know your parent element's width, height details and your image holding element css details. If you can share your code for this particular problem will really helpful to identify the matter.

Comment: There is no width set on the container itself

Comment: @cars: Without seeing your markup, it would be difficult to say what's happening. Maybe, your container is flowing the content as it wraps. Perhaps. Try hiding the overflow and then see - https://jsfiddle.net/zz6wd5rr/

Comment: I added the code into the question

Comment: @cars: Did you check the fiddle I linked to in the comment above?

Comment: Making the overflow hidden doesn't work

Comment: I have given a fixed width to your parent container. This will show a scroll bar when the window width is smaller than your container but it will keep the 4 images in line. Try this https://jsfiddle.net/cpp8quvz/2/

Comment: Inkua this does work but the problem is that it will then not be centered.